# Disable ohai plugin

Tags: chef-infra

Using oahi version 8.0.0 from the chefdk on mac.

If I run the command `ohai` in the terminal, my mac completely locks up for 10+ minutes).

Users have suggested this is caused by being connected to LDAP and recomend disabling the passwd.rb plugin. Where is that file located and how do I disable it?

https://github.com/chef/ohai/issues/1165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following inside `/etc/chef/client.rb`

```
ohai.disabled_plugins = [:Passwd]
```

Or if using ohai 7 or newer

```
Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [ :Passwd ]
```

Or point chef-shell to a specific config file

```
chef-shell -c ~/foo.rb
```

OSX users will need to make the `/etc/chef/` directory since it doesn't exist by default

```
sudo mkdir /etc/chef
echo 'ohai.disabled_plugins = [:Passwd]' | sudo tee -a /etc/chef/client.rb
```

---

(Previous version of this SO answer showed that you could rename the passwd.rb plugin, that is no longer recommended since it breaks newer versions of chef)

Comment: Anyway, ohai ignore client.rb parameters when run outside of chef run, it's not a problem of /etc/chef/client.rb presence or not. What is your use case of running ohai directly ?

Comment: Trying to use ohai to find a list of available attributes that can be used.

Comment: A chef zero run would allow you to get a full node object as json file. Sounds easier to work on for me. But this works too obviously ;)

Comment: @spuder I’m getting a deprecation warning with that. The syntax seems to have changed to `ohai.disabled_plugins = ["Passwd"]`. Do you mind updating your answer?

Comment: Updated again, it should be a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran into this, but there was another `passwd.rb` in the gems directory that needed renamed as well.  Running this command found and moved all of them for me so I could move on with my Chef travels:

```
sudo find /opt/chefdk/embedded/ -wholename *ohai* -name passwd.rb -exec mv {} {}.bad \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately in chefdk >=12.21.x this now breaks chef-shell `ERROR: Encountered error while running plugins: #<Ohai::Exceptions::AttributeNotFound: No such attribute: 'etc'>
epic fail!`